# Generate a list of unicode characters in a for loop

Tags: javascript, escaping

I am trying to list use the counter in a for loop as the number of a Unicode character.

To use a Unicode character in JavaScript one can either type it in as it is, or use an escape sequence like: `\u8211`. My problem arises when I try to combine the number part with the escaped u. The error I get is something along the lines of "bad escape character", and it means that the number from the `i` variable is not combined with the `\u` as I'm hoping for.

```
for (var i=65; i< 90; i++ ) {                                          
    anchor = document.createElement('a'),
    img = document.createElement('img'),
    character = "\\u"+i;
    img.setAttribute('alt', character);
    img.setAttribute('src', '');

    anchor.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i +": "));
    anchor.appendChild(img);

    anchor.setAttribute('title', character);
    body.appendChild(anchor);
    body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}
```

What I have tried:

```
character = "\u{"+i+"}"

cha = ['\\u'];
cha.push(i);
cha.join('');
```

... and I've run out of ideas

An example:

```js
body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

anchor = document.createElement('a');
img = document.createElement('img');
character = "\u8211";

img.setAttribute('alt', character);
img.setAttribute('src', '');
anchor.appendChild(document.createTextNode("x : "));
anchor.appendChild(img);
anchor.setAttribute('title', character);
body.appendChild(anchor);
body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));


for (var i = 65; i < 87; i++) {
  anchor = document.createElement('a');
  img = document.createElement('img');
  character = "\\u" + i;
  //character = "\u" + i; << bad unicode escape

  img.setAttribute('alt', character);
  img.setAttribute('src', '');
  console.log(img);

  anchor.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + ": "));
  anchor.appendChild(img);

  anchor.setAttribute('title', character);
  body.appendChild(anchor);
  body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  //console.log( tosay.join(''));
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-face: monotype;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>UTF chars</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How about using [`fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) instead of trying `'\u'+i`.

Comment: I haven't really studied the javascript api. Thank you.

Comment: ☞ just feed this function two pairs of hex numbers: [Yet Another JavaScript Unicode Encode/Decode](http://icompile.eladkarako.com/yet-another-javascript-unicode-encodedecode/) have fun!  ☕

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The biggest problem is that `\uXXXX` is interpreted at the time that the code is parsed; just as you can't write `'"' + '"'` to mean the same as `""` (because `"` is an actual double-quote in the code, whereas `'"'` is a string *containing* `"`), you can't write `'\\u' + 'XXXX'` to mean the same as `'\uXXXX'`.

As Brad Christie says in a comment above, you should use [the function `String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) to convert from an integer to the character you need:

```
character = String.fromCharCode(i);
```

A second problem — this is academic, due to the above, but I think I should mention it — is that the `\uXXXX` notation expects the character code to be given in *hexadecimal* notation, and zero-padded to exactly four hexadecimal digits, whereas you're giving it in *decimal* notation and without zero-padding. For example, you're writing `\u65`, but the Unicode-escape syntax for `A` is actually `\u0041`.

Comment: Non-padded integers are evidently interpreted as decimals (at least in node.js and whatever is in firefox). It's a good example of keeping the surprise factor in code to a minimum, I don't think it's a problem. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  `String.fromCharCode(i);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
character = String.fromCharCode(i); // works for me
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
charCode = 2665;
uc = '"\\u' + charCode +'"';
document.write('<a title="' + charCode + '">' + eval(uc) + '</a>');
```