# Error on concatenate utf strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I am trying to concatenate a strings and print its utf8 character. However that doesn't seem to be the correct syntax for some reason. The error is:

```
 console.log("\u" + i);
            ^^^
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

The code used to generate is

```
var _ = require('lodash');

_.times(2588, function(i){
    console.log("\u" + i);
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `String.fromCharCode`

E.g. `String.fromCharCode(0x2588) == "\u2588"`

The SyntaxError is because "\u" is not valid unicode sequence.

Comment: Or `String.fromCharCode(parseInt(i, 16))` to convert `i` to hexadecimal

Comment: He wants to build \xuuuu dynamically. hows that answer the question ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Actually, it's the answer. You can't concatenate '\u' and another string because '\u' isn't a valid unicode sequence. `String.fromCharCode` accepts as arguments numbers not strings. Just read the docs.

Comment: @Akisame There is no doubt that he should escape the `\\u`  , but still I think that he wants to get the char out from `'\\u'+'0065'`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to create dynamic sequence with the \u prefix , you can do this :

```
//65 --> 0065
Number.prototype.pad = function(size) {
      var s = String(this);
      while (s.length < (size || 2)) {s = "0" + s;}
      return s;
    }

for (var i=6000;i<6005;i++) // for example...
{
 alert(unescape ('%u' + i.pad(4)))
}
```

**Result :**

```
怀
态
怂
怃
怄
```

http://jsbin.com/vogeqotoqa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Careful though as unescape is deprecated http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

1) When you concatenate the string and the number representing the utf sequence javascript attempts to parse the "\u" as a unicode character, if you try `console.log("\u0000"+0)` the result will be �0

2) UTF 8 sequences must contain 4 hexadecimal characters, `\u0` is not a valid unicode sequence while `\u0000` is. Unicode sequences obey this regular expression: `\u[a-fA-F0-9]{4}`

The correct answer is Akisame's, use `console.log(String.fromCharCode(i));`. Also see [Generate a list of unicode characters in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746278/generate-a-list-of-unicode-characters-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: Doesn't explain the SyntaxError though

Comment: try console.log("\u0") and console.log("\u0000") you will see that the first gives a syntax error while the second doesn't. \u is always a prefix for unicode characters. Firebug gives me a more detailed error: "SyntaxError: malformed Unicode character escape sequence"

Comment: Yes, but the OP isn't logging `"\u0"`, they're logging `"\u"+0` which in this case are not equivalent

Comment: you are right, i've been too hasty into answering. i'm gona edit the answer then

Answer (score 0):

```
var message="здравей";
var final=message.concat(" готин"," свят");
alert(final);
```